# Install Joomla and install extensions-modules etc., is there any good approach for folder ownership?

Tags: joomla, upload

I use centos7 with apache, I try to install Joomla! on a folder but with the right to install extensions, modules etc. I always get something like 'permission denied' error. I can only assign everything to apache and then... problem solved! Is this the best possible solution? Drupal or Wordpress have a proper documentation telling you exactly the folders that have to be owned by apache. Joomla! docs do not help at all. All of the guides that I find online tell you to 'chmod 755' recursively, which is a bad idea. I have not enabled the FTP option. Can someone help with this?

Comment: I also tried to change the ownership of some specific folders:

sudo chown -R apache.apache configuration.php tmp/ administrator/components/ administrator/language/ administrator/modules/ administrator/manifests/ components/ language/ modules/ plugins/ media/ cache/ logs/ administrator/cache/ libraries/ cli/

I tried to install an extension and I did not face any problem. Is this something correct?

Comment: There are several reasons for this, like if you're running PHP as suPHP or if modsecurity is enabled and how it's configured. Generally, assigning perms to apache is fine.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your comment. mod_sec is enabled (even if I uninstall it, I get the same problem) and suPHP is not installed - I checked suPHP page and the project is not supported anymore. So, doing a `sudo chown -R apache.apache joomla_folder` will solve my problem but I was thinking that it is not safe..